# Whats "thank you for learning me X" mean vs "thank you for teaching me X"?

Tags: word-choice, word-meaning, word-difference

I saw a statement from  a friend of mine who said `thanks to X for learning me Y`. I said, it might be wrong and you should have said `thanks to X for teaching me Y`.

I think, `learning me` means telling me about something and then I myself go on and learn about that thing, and `teaching me` is like teaching me about that thing.

Is my assumption correct? If not, what do they mean?

Comment: "learning me" is dialect usage found in the Appalachian region of the US.  It is not proper English, and should be avoided.  I don't know what your friend was doing, but your assumptions about 'learning me' vs 'teaching me' are wrong.  Avoid 'learning me' altogether.

Comment: Take care with capital letters. Remember each sentence starts with a capital, and the word "I" is always written with a capital.

Comment: @JohnFeltz I and my friend both love southern accent. I have been trying to learn to speak it and understand it, but have failed to even say the words right, let alone with southern accent(English is not my first language and am not American so not exposed to lot's of it). Is this `learn me` being used in texas and states such as that? Is it insulting to say that or it's too informal that you would only tell it to a very close friend?

Comment: @senaps 'learn me' is widely seen as a marker of an uneducated person.  You could use it jokingly with a close friend, but I would strongly advise you not to use it otherwise.

Comment: @senaps - Don't confuse _accent_ with _dialect_. Although related, accent is how words are pronounced; dialect is more about what words are used.

Answer (score 2):

"Learning me" doesn't mean anything much. You can say "learning French" or "learning to ride a bike". The object of "learn" is the "topic". Since "me" isn't a "topic", "learning me" doesn't make much sense in standard English.

The correct standard form is "teaching me French". The verb teach has two objects, the person who receives the teaching and a second object the topic being taught.

If you need to say "telling me and then I go and find out about something" there is no single word. You could use "helping me learn French", or "introducing me to French", though it's not quite the same.

Comment: If you wanted to "talk Southern" you could say "I'm going to go learn me some French." but I don't think it's a good idea for a non-native speaker to try it unless they're very fluent. It could come across as mocking.

Comment: You've swapped "direct" and "indirect", James.  The direct object is the topic.  The indirect object represents the recipient or beneficiary.

Comment: @ColleenV Thanks for the advice, I would never use this `learn me`, and actually I told my friend it is wrong to say `learn me` but he is the one with TOEFL 98, we talked and i figured it might mean what I thought it means. good point, I can go and school him on this. (if schooling somebody is a right term!)

Comment: @senaps - Yes, you can **school him on it** - that's a good informal way to say "educate" or "teach"!