# My father taught me vs my father learned me

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

I have read like these sentences:

> - My dad has also taught me a lot about love.
> - My dad taught me a lot of things.

I am wondering if we can say "learned me" instead. So as to be

> My dad has also learned me a lot about love.

Actually, I do not notice it in sentences when the subject is ***"My father"***. why is that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Whats "thank you for learning me X" mean vs "thank you for teaching me X"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/173382/whats-thank-you-for-learning-me-x-mean-vs-thank-you-for-teaching-me-x)

Comment: The reason you don't notice this incorrect use of ***learned*** instead of ***taught*** so often with ***my father*** is probably because ***my dad*** is more informal (and sometimes "childish"). Children and people making casual online comments (native speakers or not) are more likely to be less proficient in English, and/or don't care much about correct grammar. Note that usages such as *My dad learned me a lesson* do occur with some adult native Anglophones, but this is totally non-standard dialect, usually indicating low educational achievement.

Comment: The use of "earn" to mean "teach" is a colloquialism used in certain dialects.  It's not something you should use -- *unless* you are very familiar with these dialects and the appropriate context in which you can copy them.  There's a fine line between *imitation* and *mockery*, and an incorrect use may offend someone.

Comment: Am I the only one whose first thought at seeing "my father learned me" was to assume something sexual had happened? "Unlawful carnal knowledge" sort of thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't do that. The teacher teaches, the learner learns.

Some verbs work that way: there is one verb for the performer or doer, and another for the recipient. For example, in addition to *teach* and *learn*, there's [*borrow* and *lend*](https://englishlive.ef.com/blog/language-lab/tricky-verb-pairs-gocome-lendborrow-and-hearlisten/).

You can say either one of these:

> My dad **taught** me a lot about love.
>   I **learned** a lot about love from my dad.

Comment: True for proper English, though some [dialects](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yg6kVkht3xE) allow you to "learn" someone.  OED calls that usage "vulgar"